# Label my own items

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a small financial report by latex... There are several `expenses` which repeat quite often in the whole report, for instance `food`, `hotels`, `train tickets`, etc. I think it will be convenient to make labels for them.

For instance, the first time I write `food`, I can write a label `food` close to it in the `tex` file (for example `\labelexpenses{food}`); when I write `hotels`, I write `\labelexpenses{hotels}` next to it. Then later, by writing something like `Expense~\refexpenses{food}` in the tex file, it could show in the pdf `Expense 1`; `Expense~\refexpenses{hotels}` in the tex file generates `Expense 2`. The numbers `1` and `2` are generated by the system.

So it is quite similar to `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}`, but reserved to something I could define by myself, and numbers will be generated automatically by the system.

Does anyone know how to realise this?

Comment: Do you mean a command, say, `\labelthis`, which automatically generates: `\label{expenses:1}`, `\label{expenses:2}`, etc., or a command that you use more directly (`\labelthis{1}`, `\labelthis{2}`, etc.), which expands to `\label{expenses:1}`, `\label{expenses:2}`, etc.? (The first option seems ill-advised.)

Comment: Is there a counter variable associated with each of the expense types? If so, how are the counter variables incremented? Please show the LaTeX code you've created so far for this purpose?

Comment: I felt that you were confused by my OP, so I amended it and hope it is better this time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{refexp}
\setcounter{refexp}{0}

\newcommand{\labelexpenses}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \refstepcounter{refexp}%
  \label{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\refexpenses}[1]{%
  \ref{#1}%
}


\begin{document}

For instance, the first time I write food, I can write a label food
close to it in the tex file (for example
\verb|\labelexpenses{food}|\labelexpenses{food}); when I write hotels,
I write \verb|\labelexpenses{hotels}|\labelexpenses{hotels} next to it. 

Then later, by writing something like Expense~\refexpenses{food} in the 
tex file, it could show in the pdf Expense 1; Expense~\refexpenses{hotels} 
in the tex file generates Expense 2. The numbers 1 and 2 are generated by 
the system.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have done things like this in the past:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% save text as a \ref-erencable reference in the auxfile
% usage: \labelledText{label}{text}  --> \ref{label} recalls it
\newrobustcmd{\labelledText}[2]{#2\edef\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Here is something that I want to refer to later
    \labelledText{later}{101}

    And here I go using \ref{later} again.

    \newcounter{test}

    Saving test to none: \labelledText{none}{\thetest}.

    \addtocounter{test}5

    Saving test to five: \labelledText{five}{\thetest}.

    Using the saved values of none=\ref{none} and five=\ref{five}.

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

So you use `\labelledText{mylabel}{some text}` to print `some text` and assign it the label `mylabel`. Afterwards you can use `\ref{mylabel}` to reprint the result.

This will work both with and without out [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: Oops, I see that I haven't really answered the question...

Comment: I'm a bit late, but I would be interested in the hyperref version. Thanks!

Comment: @cjorssen I have changed the code so that it works independently of whether or not hyperref is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another, albeit similar, option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcounter{expensecntr}
\renewcommand{\theexpensecntr}{(\arabic{expensecntr})}
\newcommand{\labelexpense}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{expensecntr}%
  \label{expense:#1}%
  #1~\theexpensecntr}
\newcommand{\refexpense}[1]{\ref{expense:#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Expense} & \textbf{Total} \\
  \midrule
  \labelexpense{Food}  & abc \\
  \labelexpense{Hotel} & def \\
  \labelexpense{Gas}   & ghi \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

Expense~\refexpense{Hotel} is really expensive.

\end{document}
```